# How to check for a multiplication sign in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, unicode

I'm working on a calculator program. I'd like to display the multiplication sign in HTML but also be able to detect in JavaScript whether or not the multiplication sign was clicked, so it doesn't get added to the display. This applies to other symbols. I tried using the UNICODE value, but if you press (for example):

1,

then 2,

then the multiplication sign,

the multiplication sign shows up in the display (which I don't want). Any ideas?

```js
const myDiv = document.querySelector('#display');
const myButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
myButtons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if(button.textContent == 0x000D7) {
            // call on some operator function
        } else {
            myDiv.textContent += button.textContent;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div id=display></div>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>&times;</button>
```

Comment: You need to add selectors to those buttons and have multiple event listeners. One event listener that targets the values (1-9) and then others for the operations. Classes can target multiple elements, id's can target single elements.

Comment: Using `button.textContent` in the listener creates a circular reference that (once upon a time) was a serious issue. In any case, it creates a closure for each button that isn't necessary. Consider replacing the arrow function with a real function and use *this* instead: `function(e){ if (this.textContent == ...) ...}`.

Comment: you can make an object of actions: `const ops = { '×': multiply, '÷': divide: '+': add, '-': subtract}` where each is a callback. On every keypress, do `Object.keys(ops).includes(currentKey);`

Comment: @JacobSchneider The JS method is `.includes`, not `.contains`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm really sorry, the `element.classList` has a `contains` function and I always get them confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0x000D7` resolves to a *number*, 215, which is not the `textContent` of the `×` button. Rather, simply check whether the textContent is `×`:

```js
const myDiv = document.querySelector('#display');
const myButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
myButtons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if(button.textContent === '×') {
            // call on some operator function
            console.log('× clicked');
        } else {
            myDiv.textContent += button.textContent;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div id=display></div>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>&times;</button>
```

Alternatively, if you have *lots* of symbol buttons, you might consider doing the reverse - check to see if the `textContent` is a number, and if it is, add to `myDiv`'s `textContent`:

```js
const myDiv = document.querySelector('#display');
const myButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
myButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (button.textContent.match(/^\d+$/)) {
      myDiv.textContent += button.textContent;
    } else {
      console.log('non-digit button clicked');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div id=display></div>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>&times;</button>
```

An alternative to adding lots of individual listeners with a closure over each one would be to use event delegation on the container of the `button`s:

```js
const myDiv = document.querySelector('#display');
document.querySelector('#buttons').addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.matches('button')) return;
  if (target.textContent.match(/^\d+$/)) {
    myDiv.textContent += target.textContent;
  } else {
    console.log('non-digit button clicked');
  }
});
```

```html
<div id=display></div>
<div id="buttons">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>&times;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You're answering his question but not seeing what he's trying to do, checking for times is obviously not the right path

Comment: His code says `// call on some operator function`, but said function isn't in the question, and it's not really clear what the two numbers to be multiplied will come from, or where the result will be displayed. But that isn't what he was asking about, and doesn't seem directly relevant to the problem he's running into.

Comment: Likely the list of characters to display or not should be in an array or object, since decimal points and maybe other non–digit characters will need to be displayed. Or maybe a class can be added to the containing element to categorise characters so they can be displayed or not based on the context. Or… ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As has already been suggested, adding seperate event listeners to the different button types is the preferable way to go, however if this does not float your boat, do the following:

```
let input = "";
const callbacks = {
    '×': multiply,
    '÷': divide,
    '+': add, 
    '-': subtract
};

const btnHandler = function(e) {
    if (callbacks[this.value])
        callbacks[this.value]();
    else
        input += this.value;

    // do whatever else you need to do, like condition checking etc.
}
```